# Multiplying multi-dimensional matrices efficiently

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I'd love to know if there is a more efficient way to multiply specific elements of multi-dimensional matrices that doesn't require a 'for' loop.

I have a region * time matrix for an individual (say, 50 regions and 1000 timepoints) and I want to multiply each pair of regions at each timepoint to create a new matrix of the products of each region pair at each time point (50 x 50 x 1000). The way that I'm currently running it is:

```
for t = 1:1000
    for i = 1:50
        for j = 1:50
            new(i,j,t) = old(i,t) .* old(j,t)
```

As I'm sure you can imagine, this is super slow. Any ideas on how i can fix it up so that it will run more quickly?

Comment: It seems you are doing element wise multiplication. Are old(i,t) and old(j,t) both 2-D matrices or just one element (i.e. a single number)?

Comment: They are both 2-D matrices. In fact, they are both the same matrix, but labelling them as (i,t) and (j,t) and iterating through t, i and j was the only way that I could come up with to create the output that I wanted (a 3d matrix with pair-wise multiplications in each cell of a 2d matrix (i * j) extended along the third dimension, t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%some example data easy to trace
old=[1:5]'
old(:,2)=old*i
%multiplicatiion
a=permute(old,[1,3,2])
b=permute(old,[3,1,2])
bsxfun(@times,a,b)
```

`permute` is used to make 3d-matrices with dimensions `n*1*m` and `1*n*m` out of the `n*m` input matrix. Changing the dimensions this way, `new(i,j,k)` can be calculated using `new(i,j,k)=a(i,1,k)*b(1,j,k)`. Applying such operations element-by-element is what `bsxfun` was designed for.

Regarding `bsxfun`, try to understand simple 2d-examples like `bsxfun(@times,[1:7],[1,10,100]')` first

Comment: Awesome! Much faster. I'm not sure how the permute function works though. What is the significance of the [1,3,2] and [3,1,2] parts?

Comment: Also, how would I run the bsxfun version if I needed the opposite elements to be multiplied together? e.g. (t,i) * (t,j)?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how it works. Regarding the swaped indices: You have to permute the dimensions in a different order.